# How to keep a tool running in an Ubuntu VPS server?

Tags: server, ssh, vps

I am ready to be ridiculed and embarrassed ha! So I have a Ubuntu VPS, and say I SSH into it and start Hydra, Hydra can take a while. And I usually don't stay on the VPS for that long, nor the computer. Is there a way to have tasks like Hydra stay running even when I close the session? And when I SSH back into it, have the results either in a file, or if it's still ongoing then for it to come back? I'm super sorry! Hydra is just an example, I mean any programs that need to run for awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) for this. You can attach processes to it that will stay alive after you've exited from ssh. Tmux can be installed from the [repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/tmux)

An alternative would be to create systemd service, that starts your code independently from your ssh session. The creation of a simple systemd service is described [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/)

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much, I'll check out both of those options.